# Скрипт запоминания посещенных страниц

Tags: javascript, jquery

Уже второй пост на эту тему и прошу прощения за это, но уже часов 5 пытаюсь составить простенький скрипт на эту тему.

Задача скрипта запоминать старые страницы и записывать их id в строку через разделитель. Тобишь если до посещения страницы массив уже имел такие данные "1&2&3&4", то мы проверяем повторяется ли страница, то есть мы посетили ту же на которой недавно были то оно "обновляется" - ставится в конец массива. Если же ID новый для массива - ставим его в конец страницы а другие строчки передвигаем на 1 указатель. "2&3&4&5", при новой странице с ID=5. Надеюсь понятно, теперь код.

Код странно работает. При переходе на новую запись он всегда обновляет последнюю строчку, тобишь ID этой страницы пишет в конец массива, остальные же данные он не трогает.

```
if ($.cookie('lpostset')==1) { //если скрипт задействован впервые - указываем стандартный массив через else
var postid=$("#postid").html(); //считываем ID текущей страницы
var lposts=$.cookie('lposts').split('&'); //удаляем разделители и превращаем в рабочий массив
var i=lposts.length; //получаем длину массива для цикла
//    Переменные

var n=0;
var overlap=0;
var k=0;
var c=0;
var output="";

//
while (i>n) { //тут начинается веселье
    if (lposts[n]==postid) {//если ID текущего элемента массива оказался равным ID страницы то мы его должны вывести в конец массива
        while (n<(i-1)) {lposts[n]=lposts[n+1]; n++;} lposts[i-1]=postid; break; //цикл для перемещения всех элементов на 1 слот + установка последнего слота равным ID записи + выход из цикла так как задание выполнено
    }
    if (n==i-1) {//Если одинаковых ID не было обнаружено - переносим ВСЕ элементы на 1 слот и заполняем последний теперешним ID
        while (k<(i-1)) {lposts[n]=lposts[n+1]; k++;} lposts[i-1]=postid;
    } //BREAK; не нужен, так как его выполнит только в самом конце цикла и после проверки из первого цикла с break
    n++;
}
while (c<=(lposts.length-1)) { //Заполнение строки вывода обратно в куки
    if (c==(lposts.length-1)) output+=lposts[c];
    else output+=lposts[c]+'&';
    c++;
}
$.cookie('lposts', output, { expires: 7 , path: '/' }); //Заполняем запись куки только созданной строкой
}
else {
$.cookie('lpostset','1', { expires: 7 , path: '/' }); //Тот самый Else для новых пользователей, что бы заполнить куки во избежание ошибок
$.cookie('lposts', '-1&-1&-1&-1', { expires: 7 , path: '/' });
}
```

Расписал все как нельзя лучше, прошу помощи так как я сейчас сойду с ума. По мои рассуждениям, как я выше описал, все должно работать правильно..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Глупая ошибка:

```
-while (k<(i-1)) {lposts[n]=lposts[n+1]; k++;} lposts[i-1]=postid;
+while (k<(i-1)) {lposts[k]=lposts[k+1]; k++;} lposts[i-1]=postid;
```

Обязательно освойте работу с массивами в js. Ссылок не привожу, найти не сложно. Тогда ваш код не будет сводить с ума ни вас, ни рецензента :)

```
var i = lposts.indexOf(postid);  //позиция элемента в массиве
if(i==-1){ //элемент не найден
    lposts.shift(); //удаляем элемент в начале (unshift - добавляет)
}
else{
    lposts.splice(i, 1); //иначе удаляем элемент с индексом
}
lposts.push(postid); //добавляем элемент в конец
```

[пример](https://jsfiddle.net/wgfjwfnf/1/)

Comment: Боги, а я думал я сошел с ума что не могу найти ошибку. В общем я исправил сотню таких ошибок ранее и полностью изменял алгоритм 4 раза, так что к моменту поисков этой ошибки мозги уже совсем поплыли. Кстати спасибо за пример работы с массивами, сколько пишу на JS,JQ - такое вижу впервые :)